# Rank and Taylor coefficient in Birch and Swinnerton–Dyer

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, birch-swinnerton-dyer

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Birch and Swinnerton–Dyer conjecture. I have two questions

1. Why might one expect that the analytic rank of $L(E,s)$ is equal to the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q})$? Are there any heuristics for why this might be the case?
2. The formula for the residue at $s=1$,
   $$ \frac{L^{(r)}(E,1)}{r!} = \frac{\#\mathrm{Sha}(E)\Omega_E R_E \prod_{p|N}c_p}{(\#E_{\mathrm{Tor}})^2}$$
   seems mysterious and magical. I understand each of the terms individually, but I don't see how they fit together, nor how anybody even reasonably came up with this conjecture. This formula seems so specific that it almost has to be true. How did B-SD come up with this and why is it a reasonable guess?

Comment: 1. Formally $L(E,1) = \prod_p p/\# E(\mathbb{F}_p)$. If $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is infinite, then by reduction modulo $p$, one expects $\# E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to be "larger", hence $L(E,1)=0$. If the rank is higher, then even more so. 2. Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer came up with this formula by numerical computation, and I believe they were inspired by other existing formulas like the analytic class number formula. There are analogies between the two formulas.

Comment: Numerical evidence : https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/BSD2011/bsd2011-Cremona.pdf.  A nice talk : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gbQWIzb6Dg&t=3s How the "mysterious and magical" formula fits with the geometric picture was shown early on by Tate : https://eudml.org/doc/109707. And historically the most relevant document maybe is this https://eudml.org/doc/150676. All of these documents are one click away from the wikipedia page.

Comment: The equality is *not* something anyone expected. It was discovered numerically in terms of the growth of $\prod_{p \leq x} |E(\mathbf F_p)|/p$ for many examples, and was reformulated later in terms of a rank equal to an order of vanishing. There is a classical precedent: for the zeta-function $\zeta_K(s)$ of a number field $K$, its order of vanishing at $s = 0$ is $r_1+r_2-1$, which is the rank of $\mathcal O_K^\times$ by Dirichlet's unit theorem. An important distinction: $s = 0$ is on the boundary of the critical strip for $\zeta_K(s)$, but $s = 1$ is on the critical line for $L(E,s)$.

Comment: The situation is indeed a bit different in the analytic class number formula, since the functional equation of $\zeta_K(s)$ (together with Dirichlet's unit theorem) suffices to determine the relation between the algebraic rank and analytic rank.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Tate's paper just explains the strong formula but doesn't explain where it comes from.

Comment: @Rdrr Tate even proves the strong formula (modulo the finiteness of Sha) in the function field case. What better "explanation" could you find for the formula?

Comment: Tate mentions the formula (B) in his paper prior to his proof of the function field case. He attributes the conjecture to Birch and Swinnerton Dyer. I've browsed the papers Notes on Elliptic Curves I and II and I don't see any explicit mention of the formula (perhaps not in the form above). So, historically where did this formula come from and what is the motivation for it? Perhaps its in one of these papers and I just don't know enough about this topic to see it.